# Splashscreen ProgressBar in Eclipse RCP has "dirty" corners

Tags: eclipse, swt, rcp, splash-screen

I am using the RCP Splash Screen along with the built-in ProgressBar (*AbsolutePositionProgressMonitorPart*). The splash image has a blue background color, but the background of the progressbar seems to be white, which leads to some white corners.

[image]
<sub>(source: [iachelini.de](http://www.iachelini.de/splashdirt.pn))</sub>

There is no "setBackground" on BasicSplashHandler nor does getContent().setBackground(Color) has any noticeable effect.
I don't want to be too picky, but since the splash is the first thing you see from the application, I think its very important to be tidy.
So, do you have any idea how to get rid of these corners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not the color of the progress bar. Maybe it is the color of a component behind the progress bar? Have you tried to set the color of the parent components of the bar? Have you tried:

```
setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);
```

?

Comment: Thanks for the hit. The monitor itself calls this method already btw. A cascade of setBackground / setBackgroundMode either on the monitor or its parent, has no effect.

Comment: I have experimeted a bit with the debugger last night and set the colores directly. I now think it's hopeless to try to change the colores (or try to paint with PaintListener on the component). Seems to be the native component, that draws the white pixels. And that is drawn AFTER your painting operations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to hack your way through the native component you might want to change the background image. Take an image where the white pixels do not disturb the first impression.

Comment: Well, that might be a plan. But being involved in a commercial software developement its probably not possible to change a company's ci just because some developer gets annoyed by some white pixels :)

I just recognized those "dirty corners" in the gallileo release splash screen as well.
If they don't care, I shouldn't either.
Thanks for all your support Arne. Very much appreciated.